# Matching a string to agent population

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create an event that searches a string (i.e. Operation) from a database returns corresponding equipment capable of doing that operation. However, when I try to add the resulting equipment into a collection col_EquipmentToDo of type Equipment it gives an error saying "Incompatible operand types Main.equipments_Population and String." I tried to match the resulting string from the database (i.e. Equipment) to the population that I initially created but it doesn't work.

Heres the code:

int numOperationsToDo = col_OperationsToDo.size();

for (int i=0; i<numOperationsToDo; i++) {
ReqOperation=col_OperationsToDo.get(0);

```
variable=selectFrom(toperation_per_tool)
.where(toperation_per_tool.operation.eq(ReqOperation))
.uniqueResult(toperation_per_tool.tool_reference);

col_MachinesToDo.addLast(main.pop_equipments==variable);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your database entry is a String (i.e. a literal word such as "myEquipment12"). Your collection is not. It expects elements of type Equipment, i.e. actual agents of that type.

So either change the collection to a list of Strings or use the String from the database, create an Equipment agent from it (or find an existing agent matching it) and add that to your collection.

Which one to use depends on your model.

PS: Before you ask: You cannot store Equipment agents in a dbase, only String names :)